# function numberIsEven if statement

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am working on a module in the beginnings of a web development course. I've searched high and low and can't quite find what piece of the puzzle I am missing. The instructions follow as:

*Create an if/else if/else statement inside the  numberIsEven function for the given num parameter. If the num is even, return true. If the sum is odd,  return false.*

The code editor has this pulled up to start:

```
function numberIsEven(sum){
// Check if num is Even, Odd, or Neither 

}
```

This is an example of one of the many things I've tried.

```
function numberIsEven(sum){
// Check if num is Even, Odd, or Neither 
if (sum%2 === 0){
  return "True";
} else if (sum%2 !== 0){
  return "False";
} else {
  return "Neither";
 }
}
```

I keep getting >>undefined when I run my if/else if/else statement. I need to call a variable that will change the function when it's inputed but I'm not sure how to structure the conditional to do so if it's not sum that will determine whether the computer says it's true, false, or neither.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how are you calling the function? by the way, your code will only ever return `True` or `False`, never `Neither` - because of coercion

Comment: seems weird an integer would not be even or odd

Comment: @epascarello maybe the zero?

Comment: zero is, by that logic, True @dippas - as is `false`, `''`, `null`  whereas `true`, `undefined`, and any object are False

Comment: yup right @Jaromanda X, so I'm with epascarello

Comment: You are not returning a Boolean true or false, you are returning a string. You should be doing `return true` and `return false`

Comment: what you want, (which will return true or false only) is `return sum%2 === 0;` - that doesn't check if `sum` is not a number, you'll need to check for that FIRST and return `NaN` - something like `if(!num && num !== 0) return NaN;`

Comment: @JaromandaX But the instruction say to use an if and else, so yes the one line return statement is how everyone would do it, but that is not what the lesson is trying to teach.

Comment: minus 1 for lacking detail about the question

Comment: fair enough, thought the if/else was the OP's constraint :p

Comment: `Create an if/else if/else` ... seems the question requires three possible outputs!!

Answer (score 1):

Create an if/else if/else statement inside the **numberIsEven** function for the given **num** parameter. If the num is even, return **true**. If the num is odd, return **false**.

**N.B** I think on your question last line will like this If the **num** is odd(not the **sum** is odd), return false.

for `if/else if/else` do like this,

```js
function numberIsEven(num) {
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    return 'Neither';
  } else if (num % 2 === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(`10 is even = ${numberIsEven(10)}`)
console.log(`11 is even = ${numberIsEven(11)}`)
console.log(`'9' is even = ${numberIsEven('9')}`)
console.log(`'Hello' is even = ${numberIsEven('Hello')}`)
console.log(`undefined is even = ${numberIsEven()}`)
```

Comment: so, just, `return num%2 === 0;` then

Comment: As I said in the comments The instruction for the lesson stated: `Create an if/else`, so the original way you had it met the goals.

Comment: the question asks for `if / else if / else` so three possible return values are implied!!

Comment: Woo! You guys got it. I was missing how to instruct the computer to read NaN, as well as I thought that if there were all 3 (if, else if, else) all returns had to be a string since it wasn't a boolean. Good to know that's not the case. Thank you (:

Comment: `if (num % 2 === 0) {` is true for `null` `false` and `''` for example ... check for NaN first